# PLSQL Oracle - Help to build a select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, subquery

I would like to know how to solve the following problem:

I have the following tables:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmi8d.png)

```
| data_id      | field_id    | fieldValue |  
| ------------ | ----------- | ---------- |
| 1            | 1           | Pedro      |
| 2            | 2           | Angel|
| 3            | 3           | Carlos|
| 4            | 4           | null|
| 5            | 5           | null|
| 6            | 6           | null|
| 7            | 7           | null|
| 8            | 8           | Math|
```

Fields

```
| field_id | field_description | page |
|---- |------| -----|
| 1  | abc1    | 1 |
| 2  | abc2    | 1 |
| 3  | abc3    | 1 |
| 4  | abc4    | 2 |
| 5  | abc5   | 2 |
| 6  | abc6    | 2 |
| 7  | abc7    | 3 |
| 8  | abc8    | 3 |
```

And I have the following situation: I have a table of fields only
(Table: Field) and another Data table (Table: Data).

In the Data table I have the following structure:

Your Id, the field ID (FK for Fields table), and the value of that field.

They represent fields on a form that are read and populated in my data table. And for example, some fields are fields on the first page, the second or third page of the form.

I have to build a select that meets the following requirements:

-If all the values ​​on this page are null, I should not return any value on this page.

-If only one field has the value filled in, I must return all the values ​​on that page, even the null ones.

In the example above the tables, I would have to make a selection in the data table so that:

- You must return all fields on page 1.
- No fields on page 2 should be returned.
- You must return all fields on page 3.

And this must be done in the PLSQL language, I would like ideas on how to configure this selection. I tried in several ways, but I failed in all of them.

These values ​​form the tables, I added as a test, in practice I will have thousands of results.

Comment: Please revert your edit as images are not easy to handle for quesrion.

Comment: Done ! Sorry for late.

Comment: If you want to have the sample data formatted as tables, it should not also be marked as code. (I'd edit the question but I'm not sure whether that's what you intended.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you just need a query which accepts page number and provides the data if any of the field in not null.

You can use analytical function `count` to count non null values as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select d.*, f.*, count(fieldvalue) over () as cnt
  From fields f join data d on d.field_id = f.field_id
 Where f.page = <input_page_number_here>)
Where cnt> 0
```

If you want all page data according to your logic without passing input page number then use following query:

```
Select * from
(Select d.*, f.*, count(fieldvalue) over (partition by f.page) as cnt
  From fields f join data d on d.field_id = f.field_id)
Where cnt> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `exists`:

```
select f.*
from fields f
where page = ? and exists (
    select 1 from fields f1 where f1.page = f.page and f.value is not null
)
```

This query should take advantage of an index on `(page, value)`.